# Is there reason for bundling server-side Javscript?

Tags: javascript, webpack, gruntjs, bundle, parceljs

Module bundlers like webpack provide the option of setting the target environment to options like node. Is there any reason or scenario where one would want to bundle server-side Javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

One reason to bundle would be to reduce the size of the code that need to be deployed to the server. This could be particularly important if your server side code was running in the context of a AWS Lambda or an Azure Function, where the deployment process happens dynamically, as new compute is needed, or when it's been a while since the last request (i.e. "cold start"). You can see in [this article](https://mikhail.io/serverless/coldstarts/big3/) that cold starts are generally smaller when the package size is smaller. Bundling, especially tree-shaking can make a big difference here.